# Unsafe query: 'Update' statement without 'where' updates all table rows at once

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table dbo.User defined as follows:

```
create table "user"
(
    userid         uuid not null
        constraint pk__user__1788ccac19748a10
            primary key
        constraint uq__user__1788ccad4f14aa65
            unique,
    username       varchar(100)
        constraint uq__user__c9f2845657920267
            unique,
    passwordhash   bytea,
    firstname      varchar(40),
    lastname       varchar(40),
    salt           uuid,
    organisationid uuid
        constraint fk_user_organisation_organisationid
            references organisation,
    sessiontoken   uuid,
    sessionage     timestamp with time zone
);

alter table "user"
    owner to postgres;
```

Now I have written the following function to update this user table as follows:

```
create or replace function spUpdateUser(userid uuid, firstname text, lastname text, passwordhash  bytea, salt  uuid , organisationid uuid) returns void
    language sql
as
$$

UPDATE dbo.User
SET FirstName      = ISNULL($2, FirstName),
    LastName       = ISNULL($3, LastName),
    PasswordHash   = ISNULL($4, PasswordHash),
    Salt           = ISNULL($5, Salt),
    OrganisationID = ISNULL($6, OrganisationID)
WHERE UserID = $1;

$$;

alter function spUpdateUser(uuid, text, text, text) owner to postgres;
```

So my intention is that I want to update a record in the user table (userid) and so i am placing $1 in the where clause

So why am I getting the following error message:

```
Unsafe query: 'Update' statement without 'where' updates all table rows at once
```

Comment: This is not an error message from PostgreSQL, could be your IDE or SQL-client. And ISNULL() is not valid SQL for PostgreSQL, most likely you want COALESCE(): https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL

Comment: Ok i have got this working as follows:
```
create   function spUpdateUser(userid uuid, firstname text, lastname text, passwordhash  bytea, salt  uuid , organisationid uuid) returns void
    language sql
as
$$

UPDATE dbo.User
SET FirstName      = coalesce($2, FirstName),
    LastName       = coalesce($3, LastName),
    PasswordHash   = coalesce($4, PasswordHash),
    Salt           = coalesce($5, Salt),
    OrganisationID = coalesce($6, OrganisationID)
WHERE UserID = $1;

$$;

alter function spUpdateUser(uuid, text, text, text) owner to postgres;
```

Comment: and I call this as follows:

select *
from spupdateuser('ef613f50-b1d5-433c-88e2-8c5d655bfca9','Chris','Davis', NULL, NULL,NULL) ;